# ERROR invalid-api-key PHP /CURL for Alchemy api text/TextGetCombinedData

Tags: php, curl, text-extraction, alchemyapi, alchemy

I am getting ERROR Invalid key

***cURL/php CODE:***

```
 $request = "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/url/URLGetAuthors?apikey=$alchemyapikey&url=www.ibm.com";
    //echo $request;
    $curl = curl_init($request);
   $alchemydata = array
      'apikey' => $alchemyapikey,
      'text' => strip_tags($result),
      'outputMode' => 'json',
      'extract'=>'entities,keywords',
      'url'=>'https://www.ibm.com/us-en/',
    );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $alchemydata);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/text/TextGetCombinedData");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die("Curl failed: " . curL_error($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thank you
Bhaskar

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing ( at

```
$alchemydata = array(
    'apikey' => $alchemyapikey,
    'text' => strip_tags($result),
    'outputMode' => 'json',
    'extract'=>'entities,keywords',
    'url'=>'https://www.ibm.com/us-en/',
);
```

Comment: Thank you Quynh.   Sorry for the typo.  I have that braces/bracket. still same issue

Comment: Can you please give all of your source code so I can test in my local